# 64 bit Assembly introduction

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, intel

I am looking for an articles which introduce Intel 64 bit processor and Assembly: list of x64 registers, commands syntax etc. for programmers familiar with 32 bit Assembly. Kind of "What's new" for 64 bit processor.

Comment: The ["Gentle Introduction to x86-64 Assembly"](http://web.archive.org/web/20160315213751/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html) article on x86-64.org is exactly what you're looking for (archive.org link because it's down ATM).  It uses AT&T syntax, but the concept doesn't change for Intel syntax.  See also other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/vista_x64.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286%28VS.80%29.aspx

[What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64)

Answer (score 6):

The [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) have everything you need.